# How to Make Case Override Previous Case

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I have a number of cases that generate a different image for each case. The problem is, the images seem to stack once they are generated. How can I set each case to override the previous image?

```
- (void)setTileValue:(NSInteger)tileValue {
  _tileValue = tileValue;
  self.numberLabel.text = [@(tileValue) stringValue];
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [self backgroundView:[@(tileValue) intValue]];
    [self.numberLabel addSubview:backgroundView];
  self.value = tileValue;
}


- (UIImageView *)backgroundView:(NSUInteger)value {
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]]; // light gray
        case 2:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background1"]]; // gray
        case 4:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background2"]]; // gark gray
        case 8:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background3"]]; // red
        case 16:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background4"]]; // orange
        default:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
    }
}
```

**UPDATED CODE: So the program is creating a new image each time with the initWithImage. I set the return to only return the UIImage now. Why doesn't this code fix the issue either?**

```
- (void)setTileValue:(NSInteger)tileValue {
  _tileValue = tileValue;
  self.numberLabel.text = [@(tileValue) stringValue];
//    UIImageView *backgroundView = [self backgroundView:[@(tileValue) intValue]];
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self tileBG:[@(tileValue) intValue]]];    [self.numberLabel addSubview:backgroundView];
    self.numberLabel.backgroundColor = [self tileColorForValue:[@(tileValue) intValue]];
    self.backgroundColor = [self tileColorForValue:[@(tileValue) intValue]];
    self.numberLabel.textColor = [self numberColorForValue:[@(tileValue) intValue]];
  self.value = tileValue;
}

- (UIColor *)defaultBackgroundColor {
  return [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

- (UIColor *)defaultNumberColor {
  return [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];
}

- (UIImage *)tileBG:(NSUInteger)value {
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]; // light gray
        case 2:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"background1"]; // gray
        case 4:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"background2"]; // gark gray
        case 8:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"background3"]; // red
        case 16:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"background4"]; // red
        case 32:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"background5"]; // red

        default:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]; // red
    }
}
```

Comment: simply return an UIImage instead of UIImageView & set the returned image as the .image property of the UIImageView.

sidenote : it stacks up because you return a UIImageView everytime. it should not be done like that.

Comment: Thanks. I set the return to return the UIImage now. The issue still seems to persist.

Comment: the problem is in the setTitleValue method. when when ever this code is called you are adding a UIImageView. why not keep a property for the UIImageView instead of adding it everytime setTitle is called ?

Comment: Oh I understand. How can I create a separate property for the UIImageView?

Comment: Or would it be simpler just to remove the previous image before adding another one in the setTileView?

Comment: remove is possible but you just need to change the .image :) so just change it instead. try my code below in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read my comments above. then modify your `setTitleCode` to look like this.

```
- (void)setTileValue:(NSInteger)tileValue
{
  _tileValue = tileValue;
  self.numberLabel.text = [@(tileValue) stringValue];
  UIImageView *backgroundView = (UIImageView *)[self.numberLabel viewWithTag:1000]; // edited code to avoid warning
  if (!backgroundView)
  {
    backgroundView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self tileBG:[@(tileValue) intValue]]];
    backgroundView.tag = 1000;
    [self.numberLabel addSubview:backgroundView];
  }

  backgroundView.image = [self tileBG:[@(tileValue) intValue]];
  self.numberLabel.backgroundColor = [self tileColorForValue:[@(tileValue) intValue]];
  self.backgroundColor = [self tileColorForValue:[@(tileValue) intValue]];
  self.numberLabel.textColor = [self numberColorForValue:[@(tileValue) intValue]];
  self.value = tileValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. Would you mind quickly explaining why you added the viewWithTag? What does it do? (sorry, i'm still learning)

Comment: Btw, there's a warning `incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIImageView *' with an expression of type 'UIView *'`

Comment: tag is just a property in UIView. You can use this value to find a view which is embedded inside a superview. since you dont have a seperate property for the UIImageView you have no other means to find the previous uiimageview you created. Hence you can use this tag value to locate it & set the image. (edited code to avoid warning.)

Comment: It's because every time you call the `setTileValue:` method, you're doing `[self.numberLabel addSubview:backgroundView]`, as in you keep adding more and more subviews to your label.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason viewwithtag should be set to 1000?

Comment: check the code on this line 
`backgroundView.tag = 1000;`   here you set the tag as 1000 hence you use 1000 to take it back in `viewWithTag`  method. feel free to use any integer to put for the tag value & make sure you use same when you retrieve it back.

Answer (score 2):

You're making a new image view every time and adding it. Eventually this could cause your app to crash due to memory use (tons of image views can be expensice).

Make the image view once, and set its image accordingly (just return an image from your switch statement), or remove the previous image view before adding a new one.

You need to keep a reference to the image view somewhere, ideally a property on whatever class this is. Then, just set its image property. Don't create a new image view here, and don't add any subviews. The image view should be created once, in your init method.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on which of those options is most efficient?

Comment: The first one, definitely. I assume the backgrounds are all the same size?

Comment: The backgrounds are slightly different sizes, which is why the first background can be partially visible behind the second.

Comment: I'm not the best with creating efficient code. What's the best way to implement the first option?

Comment: You might have to tweak the frame when you set each image then, using sizeToFit or similar. Or it might just work, image views often draw outside their bounds.

Comment: I updated my code. The error still persists. Please take a look

Comment: You're still adding a new image view each time!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that after the switch it's creating multiple images, then try using a

```
break();
```

But the safe things to do it to create an imageView and init it, then set its image in the switch statement, that way even if it gets placed more than one, it will keep the last reference.

Comment: The break is irrelevant since the code returns inside each case. And it's `break;`. The problem is nothing to do with the switch statement.